# Spring database initialization works only after app reboot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am finishing a training project with Rest api in Java, 
with `springboot` and a `postgresql` database.
Im trying to initialize the  database on startup, with `schema.sql`, and `data.sql`.
The creation and the `data injections` works fine when i look directly in the db through `PgAdmin`, with that configuration file.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_test
spring.datasource.username = adm_library
spring.datasource.password = admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
#hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

But, if i try to use the application straight away, i'm getting

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: the relation « book » doesn't exists

Here the entity causing error is "book" cause i try to retrieve books but it can be "users" if i try to retrieve users etc...
I found a way of making it work by rebooting the app without

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

And then it's ok.
Any explanation on this behaviour ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> **Spring Boot automatically creates the schema of an embedded DataSource**. This behavior can be customized by using the spring.datasource.initialization-mode property.

For instance, if you want to always initialize the DataSource regardless of its type:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

More details can be checked in the java doc at [Java-Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DataSourceInitializationMode.html) and [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't answer my problem. I already use what you are mentionning, as it is written in my message.